# I want to get all images which either have a word in their name, as one of their tags or as category

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to add search functionality to my website and have been tinkering with the eloquent queries I'd need to execute. Currently I've made 3 queries and each gets images meeting a certain criteria, however, I'm not sure how to combine it into 1 query that would spit all images that meet one, two or all criteria.

```
$images = Image::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
```

This query gets all images that have a name similar to the searched word.

```
$images = Image::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($query) {
        return $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

This query gets all images that have a tag similar to the searched word.

```
$images = Image::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($query) {
            return $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

And finally, this query gets all images that have a category similar to the searched word.

```
public function search($query){

    $images = Image::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->get();

    $images = Image::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($query) {
        return $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    $images = Image::whereHas('category', function($q) use ($query) {
        return $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    return view('search', ['images' => $images]);

}
```

Is this the correct way to create a search functionality? Is there anything I could do to enhance it further? Is there some obvious problem that I personally might be overseeing? I'd appreciate any tips and tricks since I believe the search functionality is important for CRUD applications like mine.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-search-multiple-columns?page=1) might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the constraint into a single query:

```
$images = Image::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
    ->orWhereHas('tags', function($q) use ($query) {
        return $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    })->orWhereHas('category', function($q) use ($query) {
        return $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    })->latest()
    ->get();
```

`latest()` is equivalent to `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`.